# Round off function not works as excepted in sqlite android mobile

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, sql-insert

Select round(1.555,2)

gives the result as "1.55" in the android mobile sqlite master

but in the desktop DB browser sqlite

result as "1.56" so the calculation miss match in mobile application

if there is any settings or else custom function in sqlite please help me.

changed "Data Type" from "Float" to "Real" and tried but not works.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using javascript as programming language please use https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer for mathematical operation

Comment: multiple by 0.01 where ever needed so its solved